# Swiftでフォントのウェイトを変える

Tags: swift, font

Swift 2.0で，コードでフォントのウェイトを変えるには，どうすれば良いのでしょうか？　Storyboardでは簡単に変えられるのですが，諸般の事情がありコードでしなければなりませんでした。ウェイトを変えなくても機能的には問題ないのですが，少しウェイトが細い方が見栄えが良いのです。

Answer (score 1):

フォントのウェイトをコードで指定できるのは、システムフォントに限られます。システムフォント以外は、直接PostScript名を、`UIFont`のイニシアライザに指定することになります。
システムフォントのウェイト指定は、`UIFont`のクラスメソッド

```
class func systemFontOfSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat, weight weight: CGFloat) -> UIFont
```

の第2引数で指定します。`CGFloat`型ですが、次の9種類の定数が用意されています。

```
let UIFontWeightUltraLight: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightThin: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightLight: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightRegular: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightMedium: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightSemibold: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightBold: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightHeavy: CGFloat
let UIFontWeightBlack: CGFloat
```

*以上、iOS 8.2以降で有効です。*

9種類のウェイトが指定できますが、じっさいに9種類のウェイトが用意されているのは、iOS9から搭載されたシステムフォントSan Franciscoだけです。日本語フォントのヒラギノゴシックには通用しませんので、じっさいに実機で確認する必要があります。

こちらのサイトが参考になると思います。

[iOS9からのシステムフォント San Francisco を理解する](http://qiita.com/mo_to_44/items/e16d93ef78ff5e0ffbac)

Comment: label.text = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
といった感じで書くのですか？

Comment: ウェイトを変えることができました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: すでに解決しているようなので、蛇足になりますが、`label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)`ですね。